# How to update/refresh Azure Cache for Redis when change occurs in records in Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I hope all of you are doing well.
I have a few questions related to Azure Cache for Redis

I am using Azure Cache for Redis to store all my customer(s) ( I am doing so because I have a minimum of 25000 customers) & each time fetching those many customers (s) in some cases takes too much time. so first I save those customer(s) in Azure Redis Cache and then use the same Cache in the other parts of the app.

I am using Azure Cache for Redis to store all my customer(s) ( I am doing so because I have a minimum of 25000 customers) & each time fetching those many customers (s) in some cases takes too much time. so first I save those customer(s) in Azure Redis Cache and then use the same Cache in the other parts of the app.

Now my question(s) are.

1- How to refresh/update my Azure Cache for Redis if some change occurs in the information of the customer in the database?

2- My cache space is 1GB so this  1GB space will be used between all Application users or each application user use their 1 GB Redis space individually.

All the answers will be really appreciable to me
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For this question -

> 1- How to refresh/update my Azure Cache for Redis if some change
> occurs in the information of the customer in the database?

You can use C# SDK to delete old values and save new values like shown below:

```
IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
cache.KeyDelete("Key");
cache.StringSet("Key", "Value");
```

For this question -

> 2- My cache space is 1GB so this 1GB space will be used between all
> Application users or each application user use their 1 GB Redis space
> individually.

Azure Cache for Redis provides an in-memory data store based on the open-source software Redis. Azure Cache for Redis can be used as a distributed data cache, a session store, and a message broker. Application performance is improved by taking advantage of the low-latency, high-throughput performance of the Redis engine.

The answer depends on how you configure Redis cache. In most of the cases, one Redis cache is used for all the users in an application, where you can differentiate between same properties and different users by using `User Id`. For eg: `7654-UserModel` (User properties in user Model object for user with ID 7654).

You can also refer to a great example of implementation here - [Tutorial: Create a cache-aside leaderboard on ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-web-app-cache-aside-leaderboard)

Comment: @Naveen Alam, did you get a chance to test this out? If this response answers your question, pls mark it as answer to help other community members.